# "Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible with image" trying to insert PDF into image column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in one MsSql database that has an image column that I store pdfs and jpgs. I need to move this data to another table in another database. So I fired up c# to build a little app, but I am getting the following error when looping through the original data and I hit a PDF (it works fine on any records that were jpgs):

```
Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible with image
```

The code that I am using looks like this:

```
statement = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[DocumentContent] ([Id], [DocContents]) "VALUES (@Id, @DocContents)";

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(statement, destinationSqlConnection))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", documentContentId);
                    byte[] byteArray = (byte[])row["DocContents"];
                    SqlParameter photoParam = new SqlParameter("@DocContents", SqlDbType.Image, byteArray.Length);
                    photoParam.Value = byteArray;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(photoParam);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
```

( row["DocContents"] comes from the original table )

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the datatype of the column `DocContents` inside the table `DocumentContent`?

Comment: Use `Varbinary(MAX)` instead of `Image` DataType

Comment: @Steve `DocContents` is an `Image` column.

Comment: @MehrdadKamelzadeh We can't change the column type because an external system was built to talk to the source and the destination database already. That system is capable of posting jpgs and pdfs to an `Image` column in the source database. It is expecting to be able to continue to write to the new database using an `Image` column. Also, for kicks (just in case we could change the system), we made the `DocContents` column a `Varbinary(max)` and still received the same error from our conversion utility. Thanks for the suggestion, though. :)

Comment: @RichardO'Neil at first you have to convert your pdf to an image and then save it so. Use some SDKs like LeadTools that help you covert your pdfs to images. But it is not a free software. Try to find a free one!

Comment: @MehrdadKamelzadeh It looks like I have fixed the issue. Your comment above made me go hunting deeper and it turns out that there was a NULL in the data; it wasn't the PDF causing a problem at all...just a dirty NULL. How do I go about closing this issue, but attribute it to your comments?